# Can't see VBA when I open XLS in OO or Libre Office

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, openoffice

I've got some spreadsheets in Office 97 format. When I open the spreadsheet in Open Office 4.15 (or any version), none of my VBA is visible in the OO Basic editor.  I can save the spreadsheet as ODS, re-open it, save as '97, open in Excel, and the VBA modules are still there.  I've got macro security set to low, and I've put the spreadsheet in a trusted location. I'm looking at

Tools|Macros|Organise Macros|OpenOffice Basic

--and nothing is shown under my workbook. I can't edit. If I select one of the library macros, I can edit, but again, when I get there, none of my VBA macros are anywhere to be seen.

I've just done a new installation. I've tried on other computers. I don't normally use OO calc for anything other than numbers. I've exported everthing and created a new XLS spreadsheet.

Do I need Java?  Do I need to start with a different XLS version? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=39990

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the goal is here.  Are you trying to create a new XLS file with embedded OpenOffice Basic macros?  Or are you trying to resurrect ancient documents created with Office 97 and retrieve the VBA macro code stored within them?  If the latter, then use Office 97-2003 if you have it, and if not, try Office 2007 or newer.  If that doesn't work, then the code may be lost for good.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to open the XLS in OO, modify the VBA to BASIC, and save as Open Document Format.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267369/cant-see-vba-when-i-open-xls-in-oo-or-libre-office.